# Is a heated bed necessary if printing with PLA?

Tags: filament, pla, heated-bed, enclosure

I'm looking at getting this printer, the da Vinci 1.0w 3D Printer, very soon as my first printer. Since this is an enclosed printer, from what I can tell from the pictures, and given that it is a PLA Printer (I'm assuming that is the filament it prints with), is a heated bed necessary? Especially since this printer doesn't have one? Or should I look at a ABS printer instead?

I plan on printing 1:1 scale props.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden the linked question might be tweaked slightly to be specific to the case of having an enclosed printer. Allowing this question to be unique. We can discuss in Chat or Meta, but what do you think?

Comment: @tbm0115 This question mentions the printer being enclosed as well - if the question were about an open-framed printer it might not be a duplicate. In any case, I don't think the answer changes significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with sticking to bed without preheat, PLA is possible to print on Kapton tape with no-heated bed. Or there are other tapes dedicated for printing. da Vinci 1.0w is good for small models with PLA. ABS is not possible with no heated bed.